# PHPUnit generated test skeleton path

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, symfony1, phpunit

Is it possible to tell phpunit where to put generated test skeleton file by the --skeleton-test command? Even is it possible to tell phpunit to repeat directory structure?
Lest say i have file for testing in `lib/model/SomeClass.php` and i want phpstorm to generate unit test class and put it in `test/lib/model/SomeClassTest.php` without creation of all neccessary directory structure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like nobody has an answer.

Comment: Can't you just specify full path to the file? Or write bash script to add it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example reproduced for convenience

```
mkdir lib/model tests/lib/model
echo "<?php class SomeClass{}" > lib/model/SomeClass.php
```

Calling the code below should do the trick

```
phpunit --skeleton-test SomeClass library/model/SomeClass.php SomeClassTest tests/library/model/SomeClassTest.php
```

The arguments (only the first one being mandatory) are

```
$inClassName, 
$inSourceFile = '',
$outClassName = '',
$outSourceFile = ''
```

as described in the constructor of `PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Class`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is possible in netbeans IDE. if you configure PHPUnit(Xdebug required) with netbeans then it automatically creates file/folder structure for your framework

[Netbeans link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html)

Also it creates the skeleton for each class of Controller and module

Answer (score 0):

/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator/src/TestGenerator.php

In the constructor change the $outSourceFile to the path you would like the file to save to.

Cheers