# How to setup NetBeans to generate unit testing for CodeIgniter project using PHPUnit

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I use netbeans 7.3, newest PHPUnit as my unit testing framework and CodeIgniter as the MVC framework. When I want to generate a unit test in netbeans by right-clicking on the php class then Tools-> Create phpUnit test the Skeleton generator should has to generate the unit test skeleton file. How ever when I did that for model/calculator.php file it throws an error. The error not describe any thing, hence it says that the test file not created.

following are the code in calculator.php file.

```
<?php
use \CI_Model;

/**
 * @assert(1,2)=3
 * @assert(2,2)=4
 */

 class Calculator extends CI_Model
 {
 function Add($n1,$n2)
    {
    return $n1+$n2;
    }
 }
```

My question is when I remove the extends CI_Model the IDE can generate the Unit test file,but with the extends CI_Model it generates the above error message. What I've done wrong here or what configuration change should I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Maybe there is a way to bootstrap all the classes that are extended by the class

Answer (score 0):

If using composer.json, add this

`"phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator": "*",
 "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.7.*",
 "Celc/ciunit" : "dev-master"`

Run composer to add phpunit-skelgen to your vendor directory

`composer update`

Via command line within your CodeIgniter's /application/controllers directory run this (all one command):

`../../vendor/bin/phpunit-skelgen generate-test --bootstrap ../../vendor/celc/ciunit/src/bootstrap_phpunit.php -- YourClassName`

Example

`[path to skelgen] generate-test --bootstrap [path to CI Unit bootstrap] -- YourClassName`

To change the location of where the generated file saves in CodeIgniter, check out my solution [PHPUnit generated test skeleton path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409205/phpunit-generated-test-skeleton-path/31614708#31614708).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your post Andrew. I'll try this